# How to create listener for Calendar in thread

Tags: java, listener

I've tried to find the solution for two days and still don't know what to do.

Here's the situation: I have runnable class where variable of Calendar type doing some increment over time through infinite loop (there's a simplified model in a *source 1*). Next I have a GUI, where I'm starting new thread (*source 2*).

When a variable 'time' changed, I want to to some math and change some labels on my GUI.

As I understand, I should create PropertyChangeListener and this is a place, where I have a problem: I really don't understand how to do it. I've done following things: updated my TimeLoop class to *Source 3*. I've created listener listed on *Source 4* (also simplified). And here comes the question: how and where I should initialize listener? Or where am I wrong? Thanks for your answers.

P.S. The only Idea I had was (Source 5) and that of course can't work.

---

**Source 1 (example of my runnable class):**

```
public class TimeLoop implements Runnable {

        private Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                time.set(1997, 11, 27, 00, 00, 00);
                while (true) {

                    time.add(time.HOUR, 1);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted error");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Source 2 (source from my GUI class):**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        Thread trTime = new Thread(new TimeLoop());
        trTime.setName("TimeLoop");
        trTime.start(); 

    }
```

**Source 3 (Edited runnable class):**

```
public class TimeLoop implements Runnable {

    private Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void updateTime() {
        Calendar oldValue = time;
        time.add(time.HOUR, 1);
        Calendar newValue = time;
        support.firePropertyChange("time", oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                time.set(1997, 11, 27, 00, 00, 00);
                updateTime();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted error");
        }
    }
}
```

**Source 4 (Listener):**

```
public class TimeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
                System.out.println(pce.getPropertyName() + " has new value);
            }
        }
```

**Source 5 (Wrong code):**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {           
        Thread trTime = new Thread(new TimeLoop());
        trTime.setName("TimeLoop");
        trTime.start(); 

        TimeLoop tLoop = new TimeLoop();
        TimeListener tTistener = new TimeListener();
        tLoop.addListener(tTistener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) useing the [Observer Patern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) would be very usefull.

Comment: Observer Patern is really useful. Finally, my code is working. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  You just need to follow the proper sequence:

1. Create instances of your TimeLoop and TimeListener objects.
2. Add the TimeListener to the TimeLoop.
3. Start the TimeLoop running in its own Thread.

> ```
> TimeLoop tLoop = new TimeLoop();
> TimeListener tListener = new TimeListener();
> tLoop.addPropertyChangeListener(tListener);
> Thread trTime = new Thread(tLoop);
> trTime.setName("TimeLoop");
> trTime.start();
> ```

The issue with your code in #5 is that the object you're running on the Thread (new TimeLoop()) is not the same instance of TimeLoop to which you added the PropertyChangeListener (tLoop).  Therefore the instance running within the Thread won't fire any events.

Comment: Also, though it's not a direct answer to your question, your code could benefit from separating the _task_ from the _execution_ of the task, i.e. getting rid of the infinite loop and using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to schedule the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with Observer Patern. Here's is code:

**Source 1 (runnable class):**

```
public class TimeLoop extends Observable implements Runnable{

    private Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            time.set(1997, 11, 27, 00, 00, 00);
                while (true) {
                    time.add(time.HOUR, 1);
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(time);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted error");
        }
    }

}
```

**Source 2 (Handler):**

```
public class Handler implements Observer{

    private Calendar resp;

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
        if (o1 instanceof Calendar) {
            resp = (Calendar) o1;
            System.out.println("Received response: " + resp);
        }
    }
}
```

**Source 3 (GUI):**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        final TimeLoop tLoop = new TimeLoop();
        final Handler responseHandler = new Handler();      
        tLoop.addObserver(responseHandler);

        Thread trTime = new Thread(tLoop);
        trTime.setName("TimeLoop");
        trTime.start();

    }
```